# Install Shield LE not creating bin folder for web project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, webforms, installshield-le

When building an install shield LE setup project for a website / web application, the resulting setup does not have a bin folder and all dependencies are installed into the root folder. Any idea why does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding a new folder to the website in [IISROOTFOLDER]:

[image]

Afterwards I added the "website.Primary output" and "website.Debug Symbols" to the bin folder.

The "website.Content Files" I left in the website folder.

**EDIT: Displaying the IISROOTFOLDER**

I added the IISROOTFOLDER doing the following steps:

- Go to your setup project.
- Go to "3 Configure the Target System" (1 in picture below)
- Go to "Internet Information Services"
- Go to "Web Sites" (2 in picture below), right-click and select "Add Web Site".
- Name the web site appropriately.
- In the properties section, go to "Home Directory" section and you should see [IISROOTFOLDER] (3 in picture below).

Now you can continue with the first part of the answer.

Good luck!

[image: Displaying the IISROOTFOLDER]

Comment: ISLE (limited edition) I don't see IISROOTFOLDER how did you get that?

Comment: Thanks for that. I was wondering how to setup Web Setup Project as I could not get IISFOLDER setup.